# Undo system for a List of Lists

Tags: c#

I am developing an app for editing GPX tracks on a map. The user can draw tracks or import .gpx files. Tracks can be changed by dragging track points, tracks can be merged, a track can be split into 2 tracks, etc...

I have a `TrackPoint` class that stores the basic elements, position, elevation, and time of each track point.

I have another class called `Track` where I store the name, grade and a `List<trackPoint>` collection:

```
public class trackPoint : GMap.NET.WindowsForms.Markers.GMarkerGoogle
{
    public trackPoint(PointLatLng p_point, Bitmap p_bitmap) : base(p_point, p_bitmap)
    {
        this.backImage = p_bitmap;
    }
    private Image _backImage;
    public Image backImage
    {
        get {return _backImage;}
        set {_backImage = value;}
    }
    // + 8 more properties... (not relevant)
}

public class track
{
    public track(List<trackPoint> p_points, string p_name) 
    {
        this.Points = p_points;
        this.Name = p_name;
    }
    private string _Name;
    public string Name
    {
        get {return _Name;}
        set {_Name = value;}
    }
    private List<trackPoint> _points;
    public List<trackPoint> Points
    {
        get {return _points;}
        set {_points = value;}
    }
    // + 11 more properties...
}
```

Since more than one `Track` can be edited simultaneously, there is a 
`List<Track> trackList` collection that holds the tracks collection. The `trackList` member is static, because this seemed to be easier to call from the 60 other classes.

Editing tracks works fine, but the problem started, when I tried to implement an undo/redo system.

First I defined 2 stacks:

```
Stack<List<track>> undoStack
Stack<List<track>> redoStack
```

to push and pop `TrackList` snapshots.
So after each track change, I issue:

```
undoStack.Push(trackList);
```

In my ignorance, I thought it would be enough to undo the changes by:

```
redoStack.Push(trackList);
trackList = undoStack.Pop();
```

This ended up in an empty `trackList` variable.

Reading further, I understood the trackList items are stored as references, not as values.
Some similar undo/redo questions mention the memento pattern, but for what I understand, this requires iterating over the entire collect (contains thousands of `TrackPoint` instances), so I don't know if this is an efficient approach and began to wonder if there is a better way.

Is the an elegant way to take a snapshot of the contents of `trackList` and later restore the snapshot?

Comment: What have you tried?  You may want to format your code, rather than a giant question with the code embedded.

Comment: Yeah, trying to read through this is really hard.  Please just post the code.  Comment in the code or in headings as needed.

Comment: Thank you Johnathon, I'll try this. One remark: Most of the time, a user edits all the tracks he put on the map (e.g. merging them all into 1 track), so I don't want to save undo info per track, always the whole "picture".

Answer (score 0):

You can create an interface called `ICloneable<T>`.

```
public interface ICloneable<T>
{
    T Clone();

    Guid CloneId {get; set;}
}
```

Have your `Track` and `TrackPoint` classes implement this interface.

```
public class TrackPoint: ICloneable<TrackPoint>
{
    public TrackPoint() { CloneId = Guid.NewGuid(); }
    public double X{get; set;}

    public double Y{get; set;}

    public Guid CloneId {get; set;}

    public TrackPoint Clone()
    {
        return new TrackPoint{ X= this.X, Y= this.Y, CloneId = this.CloneId, };
    }
}
```

Then create an UndoTrack and UndoTrackPoint class that will wrap your two classes. This will give you the ability to easily find the latest version of the object that maps back to the object currently being edited.

```
public class UndoTrack
{
    public UndoTrack(Track track)
    {
        this.TrackToUndo = track;
        this.UndoId = track.CloneId;
        this.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public Track TrackToUndo {get; set;}

    public Guid UndoId {get; set;}

    public DateTime CreatedAt {get; set;}
}
```

When you go to modify a either one of your cloneable objects (Track or TrackPoint), you clone the original track and add it to a `List<T>` collection. You don't want to add it to a stack, because you might just want to undo operations on *one* Track, but not all tracks that were edited after the first track was changed. In that scenario, you'd have to pop off changes to other Tracks in order to get to the changes made to the selected Track.

We use a `UndoId`, `CloneId` and a `CreatedAt` date to determine which Track belongs to the item we want to undo, and what change was the last change made.

We would  create the undo item like this, when the track or track point is about to be edited (maybe upon selection?).

```
private List<UndoTrack> trackUndoHistory = new List<UndoTrack>();
public void BeginEditing()
{
    // determine the track being edited.
    // .....

    trackUndoHistory.Add(new UndoTrack(trackBeingEdited));
}
```

When you want to undo it, use the `UndoId` and `CreatedAt` to replace the track with the track that existed before the modification happened.

```
public void UndoTrack(Track track)
{
    UndoTrack lastTrackVersion = trackUndoHistory
        .Where(undoItem => undoItem.UndoId == track.CloneId)
        .Max(undoItem => undoItem.CreatedAt)

    // We have no previous version to undo.
    if (lastTrackVersion == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Grab the index of the current track, remove the edited track and 
    // insert the previous version of the track at the same index.
    int indexToInsertAt = this.trackList.IndexOf(track);
    this.trackList.Remove(track);
    this.trackList.Insert(indexToInsertAt, lastTrackVersion.Track);
}
```

This general workflow will do what you are wanting. You'll have to adapt it to your project and its needs; the concept here though should work.

Comment: trackPoint already inherits from another (indispensable) class and multiple inheritance seems not yet supported, so I am afraid I cannot use your solution.

Comment: Interfaces are not inherited, they are implemented. You can inherit from one class, and implement 10 interfaces. There's no limit, so this will still work as ICloneable<T> is an interface, not an inheritable class.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that, sigh, so much to learn. This might also solve another problem in the same app, Thank you!

Comment: An important distinction is that inheriting from a class allows the child class to use all of the previously written code. Interfaces require the class to implement all of the code from scratch on each class it is used.

Comment: Did this answer your question, or are you still having issues?

Comment: Looks like it's going to work, but not finished yet. Will definitively report back, but first a 10 days holiday, I have seen so little sunshine lately ;)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was looking for functionality, built into the framework, which would allow me to state something like: DeepClone(MyObject) which would iterate over all the nested objects of MyObject to deliver a usable clone. So, to go back to my initial question: "Is there an elegant solution...", my temporary conclusion is, that the answer is no. 
I appreciate Johnathon's suggestion to not use a Stack, his argumentation is valid, but in most situations, people don't swap tracks while editing, so I stick to a stack, because its lifo behaviour makes it the logical container for undo/redo operations. It became clear, that the essence of a solution is to manually iterate over all objects, so I added a method to the TrackPoint class:

```
public TrackPoint TrackpointClone()
{
    double lat = this.Position.Lat;
    double lon = this.Position.Lng;
    Bitmap backImg = new Bitmap(this.backImage);
    TrackPoint pointCopy = new TrackPoint(new PointLatLng(lat, lon), backImg);
    pointCopy.elevation = this.elevation;
    pointCopy.time = this.time;
    pointCopy.trackIndex = this.trackIndex;
    pointCopy.status = this.status;
    pointCopy.lastEdit = this.lastEdit;
    return pointCopy;
}

And a similar method in the Track class:

public Track TrackClone()
{
    Track trackCopy = new Track();
    trackCopy.Name = this.Name;
    trackCopy.Description = this.Description;
    trackCopy.Index = this.Index;
    trackCopy.Grade = this.Grade;
    trackCopy.ForHiking = this.ForHiking;
    trackCopy.ForBikeRoad = this.ForBikeRoad;
    trackCopy.ForBikeOffRoad = this.ForBikeOffRoad;
    trackCopy.ForCar = this.ForCar;
    trackCopy.Points = new List<TrackPoint>();
    foreach (TrackPoint tp in this.Points)
        trackCopy.Points.Add(tp.TrackpointClone());
    return trackCopy;
}
```

In every method, that changes the track, I do:

```
undoStack.Push(trackList[WorkTrackIndex].TrackClone());
```

If the user wants to undo or redo the last edits:

```
public void undoLastTrackEdit()
{
    if (undoStack.Count == 0)
        return;
    int trackIndex = undoStack.Peek().Index;
    if (trackIndex < trackList.Count)
    {
        redoStack.Push(trackList[trackIndex].TrackClone());
        trackList.RemoveAt(trackIndex);
        trackList.Insert(trackIndex, undoStack.Pop());
    }
}

public void redoLastTrackEdit()
{
    if (redoStack.Count == 0)
        return;
    int trackIndex = redoStack.Peek().Index;
    if (trackIndex < trackList.Count)
    {
        undoStack.Push(trackList[trackIndex].TrackClone());
        trackList.RemoveAt(trackIndex);
        trackList.Insert(trackIndex, redoStack.Pop());
    }
}
```

This works ok, but if anybody knows a better way to achieve this with less code, you're welcome.